Create dummy if value changed between different periods on R
I would like to create a dummy variable equal to 1 if at least one value of the state of the road (road_improvement) changed between t and the period before t, and 0 if the value did not change. The objective is to obtain one observation per grid cell and period.
Here below is a representative example of the dataset I have.
data<-data.frame(id_road=c("id1","id2","id3","id4", "id5","id1","id2","id3", "id4", "id5"),id_grid=c("A","A","A", "B","C","A","A","A", "B", "C"), year=c(1961,1961,1961,1961,1961,1964,1964,1964,1964,1964), road_improvement=c(5,5,5,5,1,5,5,3,8,1))

 id_road id_grid year road_improvement
1      id1       A 1961                5
2      id2       A 1961                5
3      id3       A 1961                5
4      id4       B 1961                5
5      id5       C 1961                1
6      id1       A 1964                5
7      id2       A 1964                5
8      id3       A 1964                3
9      id4       B 1964                5
10     id5       C 1964                1


Here below is the output I would like to obtain.
data_final<-data.frame(id_road=c("id3","id4","id5","id3","id4","id5"),id_grid=c("A","B","C","A", "B","C"), year=c(1961,1961,1961,1964,1964,1964), road_improvement=c(5,5,1,3,8,1),  dummy_improv=c(0,0,0,1,1,0))

 id_road id_grid year road_improvement dummy_improv
1     id3       A 1961                5            0
2     id4       B 1961                5            0
3     id5       C 1961                1            0
4     id3       A 1964                3            1
5     id4       B 1964                8            1
6     id5       C 1964                1            0

Thank you very much for your help

Could you edit your question to clarify why id1 and id2 wouldn't be included in your desired output? Shouldn't they both have a 0 for id_grid == A?

You can achieve that with dplyr:
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  id_road = c(
    "id1",
    "id2",
    "id3",
    "id4",
    "id5",
    "id1",
    "id2",
    "id3",
    "id4",
    "id5"
  ),
  id_grid = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C"),
  year = c(1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1964, 1964, 1964, 1964, 1964),
  road_improvement = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 3, 8, 1)
)

data <- data %>%
  group_by(id_grid) %>%
  mutate(
    dummy_improv = ifelse(road_improvement != lag(road_improvement), 1, 0),
    dummy_improv = ifelse(is.na(dummy_improv), 0, dummy_improv)  # Replace NA with 0 for the first observation in each group
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 10 × 5
   id_road id_grid  year road_improvement dummy_improv
   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>            <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 id1     A        1961                5            0
 2 id2     A        1961                5            0
 3 id3     A        1961                5            0
 4 id4     B        1961                5            0
 5 id5     C        1961                1            0
 6 id1     A        1964                5            0
 7 id2     A        1964                5            0
 8 id3     A        1964                3            1
 9 id4     B        1964                8            1
10 id5     C        1964                1            0


You can use mutate to create a logical and + to convert to 1/0:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(dummy_improv = +(road_improvement != lag(road_improvement)),
         .by = c(id_road, id_grid)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(dummy_improv = 0))

Output:
   id_road id_grid year road_improvement dummy_improv
1      id1       A 1961                5            0
2      id2       A 1961                5            0
3      id3       A 1961                5            0
4      id4       B 1961                5            0
5      id5       C 1961                1            0
6      id1       A 1964                5            0
7      id2       A 1964                5            0
8      id3       A 1964                3            1
9      id4       B 1964                8            1
10     id5       C 1964                1            0

